# How can I do pattern matching in the purescript repl

Tags: purescript

I have the following in the repl

```
> :t foo
Tuple Int Int
```

I made an attempt to do pattern matching against `foo`

```
> (Tuple q w) = foo
Unexpected token '=' at line 1, column 13
```

So my question is: "What's the proper syntax to do pattern matching in the repl?"

Comment: I don't think you can. That's just not supported.

Comment: Yeah the guys at work just broke the bad news.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should be able the following way:

```
(q /\ w) = foo
```